# Find first value across data.frame columns [R]

Tags: r

I am trying to match the value of one column against several other columns, and create a logical matrix that contains TRUE for the FIRST match and FALSE for all other values.

For example, using the following data:

```
var1 <- c("bush", "tree", "tree", "rock")
var2 <- c("tree", "bush", "rock", "rock")
var3 <- c("rock", "tree", "tree", "rock")
var4 <- c("rock", "tree", "tree", "tree")
var5 <- c("bush", "bush", "rock", "tree")

search_term <- c("tree", "tree", "bush", "tree")

df <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, search_term, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


> df
  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 search_term
1 bush tree rock rock bush        tree
2 tree bush tree tree bush        tree
3 tree rock tree tree rock        bush
4 rock rock rock tree tree        tree
```

I want look for "search_term" in var1-var5, and ultimately create a logical matrix with TRUE for the first value and FALSE for all others.

Doing this:

```
df[, 1:5] == df$search_term
```

Yields a logical matrix with TRUE for ALL matches:

```
      var1  var2  var3  var4  var5
[1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

What I'm trying to get is something that looks like this, with TRUE only for the FIRST match:

```
      var1  var2  var3  var4  var5
[1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `first` entry to be only true

```
t(apply(df[,1:5]==df$search_term, 1, function(x) {
                  x[which(x)[-1]] <- FALSE
                  x}))

 #      var1  var2  var3  var4  var5
 #[1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 #[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 #[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 #[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

#### Update

Another option would be

```
 indx <- df[1:5]==df$search_term
 indx1 <- !indx+1
 indx1[cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(indx,'first')*!!rowSums(indx))] <- TRUE
 indx1
 #     var1  var2  var3  var4  var5
 #[1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 #[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 #[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 #[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```